# AngularJS, $window is not defined, how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window, redirect

i am trying to do a redirect on a click

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    document.getElementById('next_question').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        $window.location.href = '#/tab/category/1';
        return true;
    }, false);
})
```

but i get `$window is not defined`. So... how would i get the `$window` or do a redirect a different way

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$window needs to be included as an argument so that it can be injected...

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $window) {
    document.getElementById('next_question').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        $window.location.href = '#/tab/category/1';
        return true;
    }, false);
})
```